# Windows Bitmap print driver winddk OEMNextBand, OEMSendPage

Tags: windows, driver

I am observing the OEMSendPage doesn't get invoked always. 
When does OEMSendPage get called?
We have a legacy printer which does some processing inside OEMSendPage. I hate to move it to a different place in the process. It has been working but now I am working on some enhancements and need to figure this out. 
The other commands are OEMStartPage, OEMStartDoc, OEMTextOut, OEMStartBanding,OEMNextBand,OEMEndDoc. 
These all are called except SendPage.
Currently I am attaching VS to spool.exe and the printer is installed at File:port. 
When does SendPage command get called?

```
static const DRVFN s_aOemHookFuncs[] =

#if defined(IMPL_TEXTOUT)
    {INDEX_DrvTextOut, (PFN)OEMTextOut},
#endif

#if defined(IMPL_TRANSPARENTBLT)
    {INDEX_DrvTransparentBlt, (PFN)OEMTransparentBlt},
#endif

#if defined(IMPL_STARTDOC)
    {INDEX_DrvStartDoc, (PFN)OEMStartDoc},
#endif

#if defined(IMPL_ENDDOC)
    {INDEX_DrvEndDoc, (PFN)OEMEndDoc},
#endif

#if defined(IMPL_STARTPAGE)
    {INDEX_DrvStartPage, (PFN)OEMStartPage},
#endif

#if defined(IMPL_SENDPAGE)
    {INDEX_DrvSendPage, (PFN)OEMSendPage},
#endif
```

As an update I found on the following link 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/rendering-a-print-job#-banding-not-in-use
So I added the part of processing to NextBand also including SendPage.
But something is not correct. OEMNextBand gets called multiple times and the PCL has many pages. The original is only one page but PCL has so many pages. 
Can anyone suggest?

```
char  gszPageText[32767];
BOOL APIENTRY
OEMStartBanding(
    SURFOBJ     *pso,
    POINTL      *pptl
)

{
    return (pOemPDEV->m_pfnDrvStartBanding)(pso,
                                            pptl);
}

BOOL APIENTRY
OEMNextBand(
    SURFOBJ     *pso,
    POINTL      *pptl
)

/*++

{
    //VERBOSE(L"OEMNextBand entry.");

    PDEVOBJ pDevObj = (PDEVOBJ)pso->dhpdev;
    POEMPDEV pOemPDEV = (POEMPDEV)pDevObj->pdevOEM;

    // Punt call back to UNIDRV.
    BOOL b= (pOemPDEV->m_pfnDrvNextBand)(pso,
        pptl);
    if (pptl != NULL && pptl->x == -1 && pptl->y == -1)
    {
        BOOL c = DOPCLProcessingPerPage(pso, gFirstPage, gszPageText);
            if (!c)
                return TRUE;
    }
//if (!CreatePCLRasterGraphicPage(pso, gFirstPage, gszPageText))
    //return TRUE;

return b;
```

}

DrvEnableSurface to call EngModifySurface to disable banding. I don't know the pros and cons of disabling banding w.r.t performance. This is a bitmap driver

```
Edited 
**For Mono**
StartDoc
  -- then for as many pages in the document
  StartPage
  SendPage
EndDoc
**For Colour**
StartDoc
  -- then for as many pages in the document
  StartPage
  StartBanding
    -- then for so many bands
    NextBand
  SendPage ?? (what is the send page equivalent here for color)

EndDoc
```

**

```
Edited for EnableDriverSurface
    static const DRVFN s_aOemHookFuncs[] =
    {
        {INDEX_DrvEndDoc, (PFN)OEMEndDoc},
        {INDEX_DrvSendPage, (PFN)OEMSendPage},
        {INDEX_DrvStartBanding, (PFN)OEMStartBanding},
        {INDEX_DrvNextBand, (PFN)OEMNextBand},
        {INDEX_DrvTextOut, (PFN)OEMTextOut},
        {INDEX_DrvStartPage, (PFN)OEMStartPage},
        {INDEX_DrvStartDoc,(PFN)OEMStartDoc},
//added this
       {INDEX_DrvEnableSurface ,(PFN)DrvEnableSurface}
     //   {INDEX_DrvEnableSurface, (PFN)DrvEnableSurface},


    };


HSURF APIENTRY DrvEnableSurface(
    DHPDEV dhpdev)
{


    HSURF hsurf;
    SIZEL sizl;
    ULONG ulBitmapType;
    FLONG flHooks;

    // Create engine bitmap around frame buffer.
    PDEVOBJ ppdev = (PDEVOBJ)dhpdev;
    POEMPDEV pOemPDEV = (POEMPDEV)ppdev->pdevOEM;
    EngModifySurface(hsurf,......)
   return(hsurf);
}
```

**

Comment: Yeah, I can answer this but I don't have code handy at the moment. I'll get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Thanks. That would greatly help.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Hello Carey, Can you suggest what's going wrong here? OEMNextBand just freezes Microsoft word

Comment: SendPage is called when the GDI has completely rendered a page and it's ready to be sent to the printer. But it sounds like the driver is using banding, which as I recall means SendPage won't be called. If I were you I would move the logic out of NextBand and put it in SendPage. As for the freeze, attach the debugger to spoolwow64.exe and put a breakpoint in NextBand to find out what it's doing.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Thanks for responding. Banding is being used. Currently there is nothing in OEMNextBand except return True. But I see if being called more than like 20 times. What should I be looking for to figure out why Word freezes? Also, How can I put the logic in SendPage if it wont' get called. Do you mean SendPage will get called if NextBank is not handled?

Comment: You can disable banding by removing the call to EngMarkBandingSurface in the DrvEnableSurface function. As for finding the freeze, I would put a breakpoint in the NextBand function and just step through it. When you hit a line of code that doesn't return or throws an exception, there's the culprit.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Thanks for the suggestion. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Is this how I would disable it. I would need to add few more lines to return false. What would the case be?  case 'H':
  if (!strcmp(NAME_HalftonePattern, pMethodName))
  {
   Result = S_FALSE;
  }
  break;
 case 'I':
  if (!strcmp(NAME_ImageProcessing, pMethodName))
  {
   Result = S_OK;
  }
  break;

Comment: I don't understand where that code goes. I don't see any `switch` statements in your code.

Comment: @CareyGregory: I have this routinue now.   Can you tell me how to remove the call to EngMarkBandingSurface ; HSURF APIENTRY DrvEnableSurface(
 DHPDEV dhpdev)
{}

Comment: I also edited my question to post what I have in mind

Comment: @CareyGregory: Hi Carey, Can you answer the question. What is the send page equivalent when banding and color is involved. SendPage is not called when banding is involved. What is the send page equivalent then? End doc is called directly

Comment: @CareyGregory: Thank you

Comment: Color wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Send Page isn't getting called when Banding is on. From this link its the expected behavior https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/rendering-a-print-job#-banding-not-in-use. But what gets called instead of sendpage is what I don't understand

Comment: If banding is enabled then NextBand is called instead of SendPage.

Comment: @CareyGregory: So if I had to some processing in nextBand on a per page basis can I do it like mentioned in the post? if (pptl != NULL && pptl->x == -1 && pptl->y == -1){DoPclProcessingPerPage}

Comment: I don't know what `pptl->x` and `pptl->y` being -1 signifies but yeah, whatever you did in NextBand on a per page basis can simply be moved to your SendPage function.

Comment: Interesting if sendpage isn't called when banding is turned on, why do you say move it to sendpage? I have banding turned on. May be you meant after disabling banding.. move it to sendpage.

Comment: Yes, I assumed you were going to disable banding based on our previous discussion. If you're leaving banding enabled then all this is pointless.

Comment: I really don't know the cons of turning banding off. I also couldn't get the code working for engmarkbandingsurface. It's hard to find resources for windows driver development.  I am a .net developer not this ddk. Isn't the GDI doing banding for a reason? If createbitmap can't find enough buffer it does banding is what I read

Comment: @CareyGregory: Can you post some code on how to disable banding inside the engmarkbandingsurface? Please. Thank you

Comment: @CareyGregory:  Thank you for the explanation. I could use consultation. robin.toms511@gmail.com.  EngMarkBandingSurface is a part of the winddi.h file at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\um\winddi.h. It is not a part of the solution. I will try to make this quick. Should I just comment out these lines inside winddi.h. This is just a header file though. ENGAPI
BOOL APIENTRY EngMarkBandingSurface(
    __in_data_source(USER_MODE) HSURF hsurf
    );

Comment: @CareyGregory: May I ask for a contact email?  Its a try!. I understand no one likes to waste their time and babysit other peoples code,. If I can get some consultation on how to rewrite this probably using .NET I will appreciate it.

Comment: No, do **not** modify winddi.h. That won't accomplish anything other than producing compiler errors. Just remove `EngMarkBandingSurface` from **your** code, like I said. And a print driver can't be written in .NET.

Comment: @CareyGregory: I made some changes to the post to show you what I have added this morning. Is this the right way to go? There is nothing called EngMarkBandingSurface in the code. Or how you about you show me what file it would be at? I added the above shown code. It doesn't accomplish what I want but am I even on the right track ? Thanks. Also this is a bitmap driver. Sample taken from https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/print/OEM%20Printer%20Customization%20Plug-in%20Samples/C%2B%2B/bitmap

Comment: Your `OEMStartBanding` function calls `pOemPDEV->m_pfnDrvStartBanding`.  Just get rid of everything with "banding" in the name.

Comment: Seemingly super simple or I am super dense. Everything that has a "banding","band" is commented out. Now SendPage is not called. This is how all this started.

Comment: Your email address isn't valid.